# How to add/remove/update meta tags from angular app dynamically

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, meta-tags

I created a `MetaService`, which will create all the metaTags from fetching API.

Below is code,

```
  public addMetaTags(seoData): void {
    this.meta.addTag({ name: 'description', content: 'example description' });
    this.meta.addTag({ property: 'og:title', content: 'example title' });
    this.meta.addTag({ property: 'og:description', content: 'example og:description' });
    this.meta.addTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'example og:site_name' });
  }
```

But issue is, When I navigate from Page A to Page B. Already created tags not cleared.

How do I check if MetaTag's already created and update them accordingly ?

Comment: Here you can see the available functions: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

Answer (score 3):

This is the documentation: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

you can call `this.meta.getTag(key)` to check.

you can do this to update:

```
this.meta.updateTag({ itemprop: 'name', content: subject });
this.meta.updateTag({ itemprop: 'description', content: desc });
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:title', content: subject });
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:description', content: desc });
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: subject });
this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: desc });
```

If your app applies SSR feature, you may not need updateTag, no need to update the tags on the client side.

Comment: My app is SSR enabled, SSR will serve complete html file .. but Can you explain bit more why it's not need to updateTags?

Comment: You need the update if have this scenario for example:
if you have default meta tags for the app and for specific page you need to have different meta tags.
I meant no need to do this action on the browser side.
You can use this if condition: 
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) == false